# .htaccess auth with hiding target directory

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, basic-authentication, .htpasswd

I'm looking for a way I could hide directory (giving 404 instead of it) before user logging in.

For example, I have directory `/admin` and directory `/login`

And I want that the user which go on the first address - will see 404 page.

But, if he goes first at second page, he will see basic auth dialog and if he type correct login data - he will be redirected to first directory and see actually admin panel.

How to do this, could you tell me please? I've tried various combinations (including symlinks) but all I get - accessible `/admin` directory, if it was password protected (if not - it correctly redirects to 404, no matter with RewriteRule or RedirectMatch).

```
RedirectMatch 404 ^/admin(/?|/.*)$

RewriteRule .* - [E=AUTH:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    <Files login>
      AuthUserFile /www/.passwd
      AuthName PROXY
      AuthType Basic
      Require valid-user
    </Files>

RewriteCond %{AUTH} !=""
RewriteRule .* login
```

Not working (getting 404 continuously).

```
RedirectMatch 404 ^/admin(/?|/.*)$

RewriteRule ^login/(.*) admin/$1

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /admin/
RewriteRule ^admin/(.*) /login/$1 [L]
```

Not working while .htaccess is present in admin directory (otherwise it became unprotected).

Comment: If your ask for code, please include your previous attempts too. [See this checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Comment: Are you using PHP as main programming language?